# phpmyadmin - delete duplicates

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, duplicates

could you please let me know, how should I construct sql query to remove duplicates in my database ?

Please see the structure:

```
---------------------------------------
| id | search_text | search_text_link |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | qwerty      | qwerty.html      | 
| 2  | qwerty123   | qwerty123.html   | 
| 3  | qwerty456   | qwerty456.html   | 
| 4  | qwerty      | qwerty000.html   | 
---------------------------------------
```

I want to remove all duplicates by **search_text** row.
Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (after taking a backup):

```
DELETE t1 
FROM your_table t1, your_table t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id 
  AND t1.search_text = t2.search_text
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the query doesn't work correctly. DB is a bit large ~30000 records. I see only the loader saying "Loading" and that's all. I'm waiting for 15 min without any results.

Comment: @Jakub: I've tried on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30c6a/1) and it seems to work...

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the size of the DB ?

Comment: @Jakub: 30K records are not so many to process... Did you have an index on `id` field? If not, create it immediately! You can also try to limit your query (for test purpose) adding `AND t1.id < 1000 AND t2.id < 1000`. Let me know

Comment: I've used this solution:

`CREATE TABLE table1_copy AS SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 GROUP BY search_text,search_text_link;`

And I think it works correctly. What do you think ?